# Jest, How to mock an imported callback in Object Destructuring?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs

I did the tests in the following way, but it bothers me how I need to import an object with the functions, instead of just importing the functions.

this works

```
//service.test.js
const get = require('../../modules/bankUser/model/getRegisteredUser');

    get.getRegisteredUser = jest.fn()
      .mockImplementationOnce(async () => mock)
      .mockImplementationOnce(async () => mockUpdated);
```

```
//service.js
const get = require('../model/getRegisteredUser');

const testedFunction () => {
  const depositReciver = await get.getRegisteredUser(depositName, depositCpf);
}
```

this dosent

```
//service.test.js
const get = require('../../modules/bankUser/model/getRegisteredUser');

    get.getRegisteredUser = jest.fn()
      .mockImplementationOnce(async () => mock)
      .mockImplementationOnce(async () => mockUpdated);
```

```
//service.js
const { getRegisteredUser } = require('../model/getRegisteredUser');

const testedFunction () => {
  const depositReciver = await getRegisteredUser(depositName, depositCpf);
}
```

I'm triyng this ([way](https://jestjs.io/docs/es6-class-mocks#replacing-the-mock-using-mockimplementation-or-mockimplementationonce)):

```
//service.test.js
const get = require('../../modules/bankUser/model/getRegisteredUser');

    jest.mock('../../modules/bankUser/model/getRegisteredUser');
    get.mockImplementationOnce(() => ({ getRegisteredUser: () => mockObject }));
```

jest returns this:

```
TypeError: get.mockImplementationOnce is not a function
```

also I've tried to import like this

```
//service.test.js
const { getRegisteredUser } = require('../../modules/bankUser/model/getRegisteredUser');

    jest.mock('../../modules/bankUser/model/getRegisteredUser');
    getRegisteredUser.mockImplementationOnce(() => ({ getRegisteredUser: () => mockObject }));
```

EDIT

```
//getRegisteredUser.js
const { getConnection } = require('../../../global/connection');

const getRegisteredUser = async (userName, cpf) => {
  const db = await getConnection('Data-Base');
  const res = await db.collection('Collection')
    .findOne({ userName, cpf });
  return res;
};

module.exports = { getRegisteredUser };
```

Comment: I think you'll need to call `jest.mock` *before* importing the module. And yes, destructuring binds things early, which complicates mocking.

Answer (score 0):

The example you are pointing [https://jestjs.io/docs/es6-class-mocks#replacing-the-mock-using-mockimplementation-or-mockimplementationonce][1]
is related to the default export but I think you are using named export in your code.

There are multiple ways to do so

**One Way**

```
const get = require('../../modules/bankUser/model/getRegisteredUser');

jest.mock('../../modules/bankUser/model/getRegisteredUser');
get.getRegisteredUser.mockImplementationOnce(() => mockObject);
```

**Second Way**

```
jest.mock('../../modules/bankUser/model/getRegisteredUser', () => ({
  ...jest.requireActual('../../modules/bankUser/model/getRegisteredUser'),
  getRegisteredUser: jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => mockObject),
}))
```

**An Another Way**

```
We can also mock a module using the __mocks__ directory which is inbuilt feature of jest
```

And at the end never forgot to call clearAllMocks() after each test else it may impact the output of other tests.

```
afterEach(() => {
  jest.clearAllMocks();
});
```

Comment: I think I'm missing something. Is it even possible to import like this?
`
const { getRegisteredUser } = require('../model/getRegisteredUser');

const testedFunction () => {
  const depositReciver = await getRegisteredUser(depositName, depositCpf);
}
`
I've tried the first and second way, but none of them worked.

Comment: It depends how you are exporting the functions of your module. If it is in exports.getRegisteredUser= () => {
  return 'ank';
};
or in
module.exports = {
  getRegisteredUser: () => {
    return 'ank';
  },
};
format then const { getRegisteredUser } = require('../model/getRegisteredUser'); syntax is fine. Can you please share more code to understand better?

Comment: I've Edited the post.
Both ways works if I Import them like this on service.js
````const get = require('../model/getRegisteredUser');```

Comment: You need to check your npm version using command npm -v. If it is V8 or less then this syntax will not work as ES6 destructuring is not shipped yet in the V8 version that we have in node v4. However you can make your code work if you run node command or test command with the flag --harmony-destructuring like : "npm run test service.test.js --harmony-destructuring"